# Can I use pieces of jQuery Mobile in my mobile website I already made?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have built a mobile website on my own in PHP, and wanted to use pieces of jQuery Mobile to make it display better on a mobile device.

I am trying to pick out pieces form jQuery such as forms and list views to use to enhance my site. I am trying to do this with out re-writing most of my code, as I already have a nice theme I would like to keep my website on.

The first thing I tried to do was use the form elements form jQuery Mobile, and when I inserted them in my page it made everything askew.

[image]

Before I inserted the jQuery Mobile code it looked like this:

[image]

the website with the jQuery code can be found here to see the source:

http://www.beerportfolio.com/jmobile

the website without the jQuery Mobile code can be seen here:

http://www.beerportfolio.com/mobile

I think it's a CSS problem but I am un-able to find it by using inspect element on Chrome.

Update:

Looking closer at inspect element I think jquery is inserting this code in my page. I tried to take a lot of it out and it fixed the problem! The thing is I can only take this code out in chrome inspect element and I do not know how to prevent jquery mobile from inserting the code.

Below is a picture of the inspect element of the one I edited and the one I didnt:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short anwser is yes you can use just bits and pieces of jQuery Mobile.

You [can tell](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html) JQM to not enhance any specific form or button element by adding the *data-role="none"* attribute to it or you can specify a container that shouldn't be enhanced by adding the *data-enhance="false"* to the container (if you do it this way then you also need to [set](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html) `$.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled` to true). Aside from that you can always use CSS to target specific elements and "override" the JQM styling.

In addition there is a [download builder](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/) where you can specify what parts of the framework you want to download.

In your specific example you probably want to either move your sidebar div into your *data-role="content" div or outside your *data-role="page"* div.

Comment: Tried the moving the sidebar but that didnt work. Originally I didnt have either  *data-role="content" div or data-role="page" div. but when I added them it just messed thing up worse.

Comment: I am going to try to use data-role="none" but am not sure what parts I should add it to to fix the rendering issues shown in the screenshot.

Comment: I added new info, I almost got it.

Comment: I think some of your problems with your markup are probably related to the fact that you have a extra div with styling in your data-role="page" wrapper, that is your content div isn't a direct descendent of the wrapper. Perhaps if you make a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/) it might be easier to see what you need to modify?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile is an extension of jQuery, so it **requires** jQuery to correctly works.

As reported on [jQuery Mobile documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/) page:

> Welcome. jQuery Mobile is the easiest way to build sites and apps that are accessible on all popular smartphone, tablet and desktop devices. **For jQuery 1.7.0 to 1.8.2**.

Obviously, since jQuery Mobile requires its own CSS (and jQuery doesn't), things are rendered differently once included in your website.

Comment: When you built your website you used your own CSS (since jQuery doesn't have one). jQuery Mobile can't works without jQuery, and it need its own CSS, so you have to adapt your CSS to accomodate the one of jQuery Mobile, or you have to adapt the jQuery Mobile CSS to accomodate your CSS.

Comment: I added new info, I almost got it.